# substring with regex

Tags: regex

how can i get substring with regex for this;

```
someword !!anotherword someotherword
```

i want to get !!anotherword part. anotherword can contain also numbers.I want to get multiple  !!anotherword parts in a document.

Comment: What **language**? Just split and grab the first index, ie. [`s.split(' ')[1]`](https://eval.in/468694)

Comment: i want to get it with jquery. but i want to get it using regex.

Comment: Different Regex implementations have different behaviours, which Regex are you using? What's wrong with tokenizing the string?

Comment: Can you explain that more detailled? Do you want a word between two others? Any word that starts with "!!"? Which strings should be matched and which shouldn't?

Comment: i want any word starts with !! be matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
!+[a-z0-9]*
```

Comment: Note that this does not require the other words to be present. The question was badly put.

Comment: You can try this: `\s*!+[a-z0-9]*\s*` : can detect multiple spaces before and after the string.

Comment: @tablex note that this will also match `!!!word`, which may or may not be what you want. Also, if you want to extract the word, consider using groups.